# What is causing my blackjack program to crash before doing anything?

Tags: c

When I run my program, it will print "Welcome to Blackjack! Rules: " and then an error window will come up saying "Blackjack.exe has stopped working and I have to close the program. In the compiler window it says "Process terminated". How do I stop this from happening?
Is one of the loops not working correctly?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Initializedeck(int[]);
void Shuffledeck(int[]);
void displayscore(int, int);
int hdrawcards(int[], int[]);
char getsuit(int);
int cdrawcards(int[], int[]);

int main()
{
    int deck[52];
    char cont;
    int hcherries=10;
    int ccherries=10;
    int hcards[10];
    int ccards[10];
    int htotal;
    int ctotal;

    printf("Welcome to Blackjack!\n");
    printf("Rules: \n ");

    Initializedeck(deck);
    cont='y';
    while(cont=='y')
    {
        Shuffledeck(deck);
        system("cls");
        displayscore(hcherries, ccherries);
        htotal=hdrawcards(hcards, deck);
        ctotal=cdrawcards(ccards, deck);
        if(htotal>ctotal)
        {
            printf("You Win!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Computer Wins. :( ");
        }
        printf("Do you want to continue?(y/n)");
        scanf("%c", &cont);
    }

return 0;
}

void Initializedeck(int deck[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<52)
    {
        deck[i]=i;
        i++;
    }

}

void Shuffledeck(int deck[])
{
    int hold;
    int max=51;
    int random;

    while(max>=0)
    {
      random=rand()%(max)+1;

      hold=deck[max];
      deck[max]=random;
      random=hold;
      max--;
    }
}

void displayscore(int hcherries, int ccherries)
{
    printf("Human: %i(cherries)   Computer: %i(cherries)", hcherries, ccherries);
}

int hdrawcards(int hcards[], int deck[])
{

     char answer;
     int i=0;
     int score=0;
     int total=0;
     char rank;
     int worth;
     char suit;
     int card;

     printf("Do you want to draw a card? (y/n)");
     scanf("%c", &answer);
     while(answer=='y' && total<21)
     {
         score=score+deck[i];
         hcards[i]=deck[i];
         card=hcards[i];
         worth=hcards[i]%13;
         if(worth==10)
         {
             rank='T';
         }
         else if (worth==11)
         {
             rank='J';
         }
         else if (worth==12)
         {
             rank='Q';
         }
         else if (worth==13)
         {
             rank='K';
         }
         else if(worth==1)
         {
             rank='A';
         }
         else
         {
             rank=worth;
         }

         if(worth>10)
         {
             worth=10;
         }

         total=total+worth;
         suit=getsuit(card);
         printf("%c%c\n", rank, suit);
         printf("Total: %i", total);
         i++;
         scanf("%c", &answer);

     }
return total;
}

int cdrawcards(int ccards[], int deck[])
{
    int i=26;
    int total;
    int score;
    int worth;
    char rank;
    char suit;
    int card;

    while(total<18)
    {
         score=score+deck[i];
         ccards[i]=deck[i];
         card=ccards[i];
         worth=ccards[i]%13;
         if(worth==10)
         {
             rank='T';
         }
         else if (worth==11)
         {
             rank='J';
         }
         else if (worth==12)
         {
             rank='Q';
         }
         else if (worth==13)
         {
             rank='K';
         }
         else if(worth==1)
         {
             rank='A';
         }
         else
         {
             rank=worth;
         }

         if(worth>10)
         {
             worth=10;
         }

         total=total+worth;
         suit=getsuit(card);
         printf("             %c%c\n", rank, suit);
         printf("              Total: %i", total);
         i++;
    }
    return total;
}

char getsuit(int card)
{
    char suit;

    if(card<13)
    {
        suit='S';
    }
    else if(card>=13 && card<26)
    {
        suit='H';
    }
    else if(card>=26 && card<39)
    {
        suit='D';
    }
    else if(card>=39 && card<52)
    {
        suit='C';
    }

    return suit;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger?  That is first thing to do.  Leaning how to debug a program is just as important as learning the language.

Comment: Here's how you could debug your own program.  Put printf statements all over your program, especially at the beginning of every function.  Then run your program.  You will be able to trace how far your program ran before it crashed.  Now put more printf statements near where you think the program crashed until you can isolate the exact line that it crashed on.  Now you just have to figure out what was wrong with your program at that line.  If you have access to a debugger, by all means learn how to use it instead of using printfs.

Comment: yep, those are good comments. You are probably getting division by zero in your shuffle. But your shuffle function is messed up anyway and won't do anything like shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array overflow in `cdrawcards()`:

```
int ccards[10];
...
ctotal = cdrawcards(ccards, deck);
...

int cdrawcards(int ccards[], int deck[])
{
    int i = 26;
    ...
        ccards[i] = deck[i]; //Overflow, ccards[] only has 10 elements
```

Either change the initial value of `i` or make the array larger `int ccards[52]`. I would also add an explicit check in `cdrawcards()` and `hdrawcards()` to ensure you don't overflow the arrays, like:

```
while (total < 18 && i < 10)
```

For example, in `hdrawcards()` you can overflow the array if you get a bunch of low value cards in a row (ex: 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3(overflow), 3, ...).